# Problems When Grabbing Information in JSON File (PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, json

So I am trying to just grab some data from a json file in php which should be simple but is not working

```
$url = 'http://www.vam.ac.uk/api/json/museumobject';
$contents = array(file_get_contents($url));
var_dump($contents);
```

this returns the contents of the file.

Whenever I try to grab data it doesn't work.

```
 var_dump($contents[0].records.[0].object);
```

this returns the whole file.

Any suggestions to return just one piece of information in this json file:
http://www.vam.ac.uk/api/json/museumobject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try JSON decoding :

```
$contents = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));  

// var_dump($contents);

print_r ($contents->records[0]);
print_r ($contents->records[0]->fields);
```

Comment: Yeah, but then how would I get a specific piece of data in that file?

Comment: PHP's syntax to access sub-elements is `->`.

Comment: I modified the answer to give you an example

Answer (score 1):

Use `json_decode` and then pass true to have it return an associative array if that's needed. [Source](http://php.net/json_decode)

```
$contents = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);  
$contents[0]->name
```

Then your `$contents` will be accessible as an array and `name` is an attribute of your object you would like to access.